# Program stop on AuthenticateAsServer method (.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tcp, https

I write MITM HTTPS Proxy. But when I try AuthenticateAsServer it stop and after few time program write "Connection was closed". What problems can be here?

```
            static readonly TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4502);
            Listener.Start();
            var client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Socket client = (Socket)sclient.Client;
            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int clientBytes = 0;
            string data = "";
            do
            {
                clientBytes = ns.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, clientBytes);
            } while (clientBytes == BUFFER_SIZE);
            Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

    var clientStream = new SslStream(sclient.GetStream(), false, SslValidationCallback, null);

    clientStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

Certificate here was create next way

```
makecert -n CN=MyCA -cy authority -a sha1 -sv “MyCA.pvk” -r MyCA.cer
certmgr -add -all -c MyCA.cer -s -r LocalMachine Root
makecert -n CN=*mail.ru -ic MyCA.cer -iv MyCA.pvk -a sha1 -sky exchange -pe -sr currentuser -ss my SslServer.cer
```

Comment: Did I get this right? You are trying to create a server that impersonates mail.ru with an untrusted certificate and are surprised the clients close the connection?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund, I instal this cert as trusted on computer with this proxy. It's don't work?

Comment: It must be trusted by the clients browsers. IE uses the local certmgr but firefox has its own certificate store.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund and here is no way to create MITM HTTPS Proxy?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Did I get this right? If I install my Root certificate as trusted root certificate on client machines it will be work?